# How to deploy node app to docker using maven

Tags: node.js, docker

Im new to Docker. What is the best way to deploy node projects into docker? Previously i use maven to deploy my non node projects and ran them as jars. Can i do this with node and docker?

Answer (score 0):

To create Docker images of my various project I use this plugin: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin

Sincerely